# Soap error in webservice on one server but not the other

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have an ASP.NET webservice which is deployed on Server2008 IIS7. We use two servers, Production and UAT (test server) and this webservice is deployed on both servers, the same compile is on both of them (no code changes, revisions etc, pure copy/paste from one to another).

The only difference between the applications is a connection string in web.config, one points to PROD database, the other UAT.

If I make a call to the test webservice I get an expected response and all is well, but when I do the same thing on the production webservice I promptly get and error

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am suspecting there must be a configuration issue as the webservices are running under their own Pool which is run by a service account/user (local admin on the servers) and they are set to only run through SSL (https:// only) on a special port.
I tired sniffing with Fiddler and got two identical SOAP requests, the only difference being the server name in URL. I can access the WSDL of both webservices from IE browser, I can successfully refresh my web reference in Visual studio (for both prod and uat services).

Does anyone have any hints what should I be looking at, perhaps someone had a similar problem?

Comment: it should give you a stacktrace of the error including the line number... start investigating on that.

Comment: Stacktrace message is the above error, line number returned is the exact line where I invoke the webservice from my test application.

Comment: so if it is, then that is your problem there. i mean, have you tried to attach the debugger to see where it hits? Did you look at your code on that line number to see what the object is being reference? it is a null reference exception so you are trying to use an object (invoking it) when it is null

Comment: Webservices are the same on both servers, I call them with the same piece of code from my test application, I only switch the URL in web.config. The test works, production fails. If the object was null I cannot understand how could it be only for the production webservice.

Comment: attach a debugger to the troublesome server and see whats going on. alternatively I would add debugging information in your code and deploy it and see what you get. you haven't shown us the full code where the error happens. it would be most helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. As I suspected the error was in production server configuration. When the sys team added a service user into the local Administrators they added it through Active directory groups, which as I am told requires a logoff/logon or a restart.

Server restart was the solution in my case.